# How to subtract 30 days from a current Date in c++ using poco library?

Tags: c++11, poco, poco-libraries

How to subtract 30 days from a current Date in c++ using poco library ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DateTime.html#11211), there's a perfectly conventional overload of `operator -=`.

Comment: Any sample example could u help ?

Answer (score 0):

First approach is to substract to the date a new DateTime constructed like this:

```
Poco::DateTime(0, 0, 30);
```

But it is not allowed at runtime because month must be greater than 1.
The solution is to use a Timespan:

```
Poco::DateTime date = Poco::DateTime();
std::cout << Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(date, Poco::DateTimeFormat::ASCTIME_FORMAT) << std::endl;
date = Poco::DateTime(date.timestamp() - Poco::Timespan(30 * 24 * 60 * 60, 0)); // 30 days in seconds;
std::cout << Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(date, Poco::DateTimeFormat::ASCTIME_FORMAT) << std::endl;
```

This is the output of this code snippet:

```
Fri Sep 18 08:18:21 2020
Wed Aug 19 08:18:21 2020
```

Comment: Can we get only Date Format instead of Date-Time Like for example todays date is 2020-09-18, I need 2020-08-19 ? one way is to truncate the value before "T" any other option which give date format only

Comment: You can do whatever you want with format. See https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DateTimeFormatter.html#11280.