# How to get Current date using Poco ? (Only Date) No Time Stamp

Tags: c++11, poco, poco-libraries

Is there a way we get a Date only from Poco ? One way is to get the Poco DateTime stamp and truncate the Date, But is there any way which gives directly current Date ?
Like for example I am using like this to get Date

```
void getTimestamp(std::string &out_iTimestamp)
{
   //Get the CurrentTimestamp
   Poco::Timestamp t_oCurTimestamp;
   Poco::DateTimeFormatter t_oFormatter;
   string t_strDateTime;
   t_oFormatter.append(t_strDateTime, t_oCurTimestamp, Poco::DateTimeFormat::ISO8601_FORMAT);
   out_iTimestamp = t_strDateTime;
```

}
Now I am truncating the Date

```
std::string t_strDateTime;
std::string t_strDate;
getTimestamp(t_strDateTime);
//extract the only Date from DateTimeStamp
std::size_t found = t_strDateTime.find('T');
if (found != std::string::npos){
    t_strDate = t_strDateTime.substr(0,found);
}
```

Any one know the simple way ?

Answer (score 1):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940303/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-a-current-date-in-c-using-poco-library), use Poco::DateTimeFormatter with your own format:

```
Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(date, "%d/%m/%Y");
```

Comment: Thanks I did the same way

Comment: @Gaurav, Please mark this as the answer if it helped you.